# Find a file and redirect the content of the first file found on screen

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to find a file in the system and display the contents of the first file found:

```
Find . -name "MyFile"| head -n 1
```

This command shows me only the first found file name.
Can someone help me with displaying the content of this first found file, in the one liner command. Is it possible to write a one liner for this or I should write a shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the command that worked for me.

```
cat $( find . -name 'MyFile' -print | sed 1q)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find . -name "MyFile" -exec head -1 {} \;
```

Edit: sorry, I just read that you only need the first result, then I think this will work instead:

```
find . -name "MyFile" | head -1 | xargs -d "\n" head -1
```